# fallo backups en shell linux

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

estoy intentando hacer un backup de los ficheros que han sido modificados en una carpeta introducida previamente por terminal.
Si el nombre de la carpeta no se introduce crear una por defecto con la fecha y hora actuales.
El problema viene cuando hago los ifs no me funcionan juntos, pero si separados. Es decir, si hago un if y compilo funciona y cuando hago el otro tambien, pero cuando los junto me da el siguiente error:

> mkdir: cannot create directory ‘’: No such file or directory
>
> > cp: '/home/edu04/practica_1/ejercicio_6/fichero_2' and '../../practica_1/ejercicio_6/fichero_2' are the same file
> >
> > > cp: '/home/edu04/practica_1/ejercicio_6/hola.txt' and '../../practica_1/ejercicio_6/hola.txt' are the same file

adjunto codigo que estoy usando.

```
NOM="$1"
find /home/edu04/practica_1/ejercicio_6 -type f -mtime 0 > lista.txt
    if [ "$NOM" != 0 ]
    then
            mkdir "$NOM"
            for i in $(cat lista.txt); do
                    cp -r "$i" ../../practica_1/ejercicio_6/$NOM
            done
    elif [ "$NOM" == 0 ]
    then
            DEF="$(date +%F_%T)"
                    mkdir "$DEF"
                    for i in $(cat lista.txt); do
                            cp -r "$i" ../../practica_1/ejercicio_6/$DEF
                    done
    fi
    rm lista.txt
```

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: más que if y elif, podrías usar `if / else`, ¿no? A todo esto, el error que muestras indica algún tipo de error con los caracteres, pues está intentando crear un directorio vacío. ¿Has intentado hacer un `echo` para ver qué valor tiene `DEF`o `NOM`?

Comment: lo he hecho tanto con if/elif como con if/else y me pasa lo mismo, cuando intento ejecutar el programa sin ingresar un parametro $1 me da error.
He editado el error exacto

Comment: fíjate en el error: "cp: '/...hola.txt' ..hola.txt' are the same file". Estás usando el mismo directorio como entrada y salida. ¿Seguro que quieres esto?

Comment: en teoria el directorio de entrada es: 
`../../practica_1/ejercicio_6/archivo_1`
y el de salida: 
`../../practica_1/ejercicio_6/$DEF/ "aqui van todos las copias"`

no se por que me aparece eso. 
Repito que cuando intento hacer los if de forma paralela, es decir quitandolos y yendo bloque a bloque el script funciona.

Comment: Ya veo lo que pasa. Como haces `cp -r "$i" .../$NOM` y "$NOM" tiene espacios, se rompe la cosa porque recibe múltiples parámetros. Debes poner comillas alrededor de toda la segunda cadena: `cp -r "$i" "../../practica_1/ejercicio_6/$NOM"`

Comment: agradezco tu comentario @fedorqui pero no es ese el problema, me da el mismo error. $NOM ademas no tiene espacios en el nombre